# AngularJS How to call a function if any of the text area changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to call a function if any of the textbox ( textarea) changes. I know that I can write use onChange, but then I will have to write it for every text.
Any better way to do it. It would be really nice if I come to know which text field has changed

Comment: see custome directives in angularjs

Answer (score 1):

If you've binded your textboxes to scope, you can use `$watch` to do that.

```
$scope.$watch($scope.values, function() {
  // do what you want to do
}, true);
```

Comment: thanks .. but again it has to be written for every binded data .. +1 for it works for Scope data . Using loops I can find it .. but again question remains the same. How to do it for all the textboxes .... it is possible ?

Comment: If you dont want to binded data or element, no else way in angular. Or you can use jQuery, like `$("form input").change()`.

Comment: no I want to check it for the binded data only but do not want to write code for every binded data in new version of angularJS they have watchGroup (I guess 1.3) but again in watch group also you have to write the mention name of the binded data in a comma seperated.

Comment: what about `$watchCollection`?